# Mathematical logic book with answers to exercises

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, self-learning, advice

I'm sure a question similar to mine has been asked before, but I am looking for a mathematical logic book with answers to the exercises. I am studying independently and although I have good logic texts I'd like to be able to check my work after completing exercises. I really appreciate any advice!

Comment: For the most helpful answers, you really need to tell us what level of book you want -- "mathematical logic" can cover all sorts of degrees of sophistication. Perhaps it would be better to ask: *Is there a book rather like $X$ but which gives answers to the exercises?*.

Comment: What language would you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

Later editions of Mendelson's classic *Mathematical Logic* text have answers to many exercises. But I don't know whether that it is the level and style of text you want.